# Number of days spent in each STATE in r

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate the number of days that a patient spent during a given state in R.

The image of an example data is included below. I only have columns 1 to 3 and I want to get the answer in column 5. I am thinking if I am able to create a date column in column 4 which is the first recorded date for each state, then I can subtract that from column 2 and get the days I am looking for.

I tried a `group_by(MRN, STATE)` but the problem is, it groups the second set of 1's as part of the first set of 1's, so does the 2's which is not what I want.

[image: example data]

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mdy_hm` to change `OBS_DTM` to `POSIXct` type, `group_by` `ID` and `rleid` of `STATE` so that first set of 1's are handled separately than the second set. Use `difftime` to calculate difference between  `OBS_DTM` with the minimum value in the group in days.

If your data is called `data` :

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(OBS_DTM = lubridate::mdy_hm(OBS_DTM)) %>%
  group_by(MRN, grp = data.table::rleid(STATE)) %>%
  mutate(Answer = as.numeric(difftime(OBS_DTM, min(OBS_DTM),units = 'days'))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp) -> result

result
```

Comment: thank you very much, I think the code works perfectly as I wanted it. I didn't know of the rleid function that did the trick. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(ID, State) %>% 
    mutate(priorObsDTM = lag(OBS_DTM)) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(priorObsDTM)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(Answer = as.numeric(OBS_DTM - priorObsDTM, units = 'days'))
```

The dataframe I used for this example:

```
df <- df <- data.frame(
  ID = 1,
  OBS_DTM = as.POSIXlt(
    c('2020-07-27 8:44', '2020-7-27 8:56', '2020-8-8 20:12', 
      '2020-8-14 10:13', '2020-8-15 13:32')
  ),
  State = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df

# A tibble: 3 x 5
#      ID OBS_DTM             State priorObsDTM         Answer   
#   <dbl> <dttm>              <dbl> <dttm>              <dbl>   
# 1     1 2020-07-27 08:56:00     1 2020-07-27 08:44:00   0.00833
# 2     1 2020-08-14 10:13:00     2 2020-08-08 20:12:00   5.58
# 3     1 2020-08-15 13:32:00     2 2020-08-14 10:13:00   1.14
```

Comment: Thank you William for the post. I did the grouping by ID and State but for an ID that moves from 1 to 2 and then back to 1, I want to treat the second set of I's as new and start calculating the days from there. Also filtering only the non-NA values will make me lose the starting time points. The answer above by @Ronark Shah works for that. purpose.